# Getting specific user in json using php

Tags: php, json

So, I looked some things up, and this is what i've got so far:

the php code to get the users from the file  userstest.json:

```
$str = file_get_contents('../json/userstest.json');
$json = json_decode($str, true);
```

and this is the code i've got inside the userstest.json  file:

```
 {
        "users": [
             {
                "id": "1",
                "username": "BrainyXwire",
                "tickets": "0",
                "warnings": "0",
                "methusscore": "0",
                "rank": "user",
                "banned": "no",
                "online": "0"
             },
             {
                "id": "2",
                "username":"Thinglord129",
                "tickets": "0",
                "warnings": "0",
                "methusscore": "400",
                "rank": "admin",
                "banned": "no",
                "online": "0"
             }
        ]
    }
```

is there a way to select only the second user from the users array based on username?
I'm kinda stuck right now :S

Greetings,  Damien.

Comment: so, what did you try.

Comment: So you want to go through all users and check if the name is: `Thinglord129` and if yes print the entire user?

Comment: What do you mean by "second ... based on username"? Do you mean you want user names alphabetized and then you get the second one from the list, or do you just want to get the second item in the users array (i.e. item at index 1)?

Comment: I guess that what Damien wants to achieve is to fetch a user from a list without knowing it's index.

Answer (score 1):

For fun:

```
$username = 'Thinglord129';
$result = $json['users'][array_search($username,
                         array_column($json['users'], 'username'))];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and a callback function.

If there would be only one user with this name:

```
$name = "Thinglord129";
$user = array_pop(
    array_filter(
        $json['users'],
        function ($item) use ($name) {
            return $item['username'] === $name;
        }
    )
);
```

if there could be several users:

```
$name = "Thinglord129";
$users = array_filter(
    $json['users'],
    function ($item) use ($name) {
        return $item['username'] === $name;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findUserArrayByUsername($username){
    global $json;
    array_filter($json, function($k){
        return $k == $username;
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}

//Usage : 
findUserArrayByUsername("Thinglord129");
```